# Divide string containing some keywords into list using Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, list

I am trying to parse /etc/network/interfaces config file in Ubuntu so I need divide string into list of strings where each string begins with one of the given keywords.

According to manual:

> The  file  consists of zero or more "iface", "mapping", "auto", "allow-" and "source" stanzas.

So If the file contains:

```
auto lo eth0
allow-hotplug eth1

iface eth0-home inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I would like to get list:

> ['auto lo eth0', 'allow-hotplug eth1', 'iface eth0-home inet static\n   address...']

Now I have function like this:

```
def get_sections(text):
    start_indexes = [s.start() for s in re.finditer('auto|iface|source|mapping|allow-', text)]
    start_indexes.reverse()
    end_idx = -1
    res = []
    for i in start_indexes:
        res.append(text[i: end_idx].strip())
        end_idx = i
        res.reverse()
    return res
```

But it isn't nice...

Comment: Alternatively, you could use something like [confparse](http://code.google.com/p/confparse/), which apparently supports network interface files.

Comment: You can simplify this code quite a bit by extracting the slices directly from the start_indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single regex:

```
>>> reobj = re.compile("(?:auto|allow-|iface)(?:(?!(?:auto|allow-|iface)).)*(?<!\s)", re.DOTALL)
>>> result = reobj.findall(subject)
>>> result
['auto lo eth0', 'allow-hotplug eth1', 'iface eth0-home inet static\n    address 192.168.1.1\n    netmask 255.255.255.0']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:auto|allow-|iface)   # Match one of the search terms
(?:                     # Try to match...
 (?!                    #  (as long as we're not at the start of
  (?:auto|allow-|iface) #  the next search term):
 )                      #  
 .                      # any character.
)*                      # Do this any number of times.
(?<!\s)                 # Assert that the match doesn't end in whitespace
```

Of course you can also map the results into a list of tuples as requested in your comment:

```
>>> reobj = re.compile("(auto|allow-|iface)\s*((?:(?!(?:auto|allow-|iface)).)*)(?<!\s)", re.DOTALL)
>>> result = [tuple(match.groups()) for match in reobj.finditer(subject)]
>>> result
[('auto', 'lo eth0'), ('allow-', 'hotplug eth1'), ('iface', 'eth0-home inet static\n    address 192.168.1.1\n    netmask 255.255.255.0')]
```

Comment: For the first time it seems little complicated, but is short and much better than my version. But would it be hard to get list of (group, string) e.g. `[('auto', 'auto lo eth0'), ('iface', iface eth0 inet static'), ...]`??

Answer (score 2):

Your were very close to a clean solution when you computed the start indicies.  With those, you can add a single line to extract the required slices:

```
indicies = [s.start() for s in re.finditer(
            'auto|iface|source|mapping|allow-', text)]
answer = map(text.__getslice__, indicies, indicies[1:] + [len(text)])
```

Comment: This is nice too, but needs little fix for me: `map(text.__getslice__, indicies, indicies[1:] + [len(text)])`

Comment: @marcinpz Okay, edited to match your requirements.  I think this is much cleaner than creating a giant, hairy regex.